# Сетевой запрос на JavaScript

Tags: javascript, api, fetch

Всем привет! Помогите пожалуйста с проблемкой! Хотел сделать переводчик используя API Переводчик Яндекса!
Всё работает, слова и фразы переводятся, но чтобы перевести новое слово или тоже слово, но на другой язык, нужно перезагрузить страницу. Кто знает, как это исправить? Заранее спасибо!

```js
 const btn = document.querySelector('button'),
          translate = document.querySelector('.translate'),
          select = document.getElementById('select');

 const input = document.getElementById('input');

 let langsUrl = 'https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/getLangs',
     detectionUrl = 'https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/detect',
     translateUrl = 'https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate';
  
 const keyAPI = 'trnsl.1.1.20200531T180817Z.d7e5b6d5df079e59.226d2cb7945705ee16e84de853179fdf20048fb7';

 // Получакм список доступных языков от Яндекс
 const getLangs = () => {
  langsUrl += '?key=' + keyAPI;
  langsUrl += '&ui=ru';
 
  fetch(langsUrl)
   .then(data => data.json())
   .then(data => {
    for (let item in data.langs) {
     select.innerHTML += `<option value="${item}">${data.langs[item]}</option>`;
    }
   })
   .catch(err => (console.error(err)))
 };

 getLangs();


 // По клику определяем язык введенного слова и переводим его
 btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  const inputValue = input.value;
  const selectValue = select.value;

  if (inputValue == '' || !isNaN(inputValue)) {
   translate.textContent = 'Вы не ввели слово!'
  } else {
   detectionUrl += '?key=' + keyAPI;
   detectionUrl += "&text=" + inputValue;
 
   fetch(detectionUrl)
    .then(data => data.json())
    .then(data => {
 
     translateUrl += '?key=' + keyAPI;
     translateUrl += "&text=" + inputValue;
     translateUrl += '&lang=' + data.lang + '-' + selectValue;
 
     fetch(translateUrl)
      .then(data => data.json())
      .then(data => {
       const [text] = data.text;
       translate.textContent = text;
      })
      .catch(err => console.error(err))
 
    })
  }

 });
```

Comment: а что дает перезагрузка страницы???? почему без нее нельзя? переменные какие-то не сбарсываются..или что?

Answer (score 0):

Исправил, убрал translateUrl из глобальной зоны видимости и запилил внутрь обработчика клика и убрал data.lang.
При переводе нового слова или того же слова, но на другой язык, новый и старый translateUrl складывались, т.е translateUrl ровнялся https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate +
https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate, в этом и была проблема.
Ну и исходный язык не определялся, поэтому просто убрал data.lang